# Execute if VM-Name is in vm.txt

Tags: powershell

a Powershell Script should start, if a vm-name exists in a vm.txt File.
Example:

```
get-vm | foreach-object -process {
If ($_.Name --matches one of the entries in the .txt File) {
execute this part }
else { execute this part }
```

vm.txt File: 
server01
server02
server03

Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `-contains` operator to check if a list of names contains a particular name:

```
$vmlist = Get-Content vm.txt

Get-VM | % {
  if ( $vmlist -contains $_.Name ) {
    # execute this part
  } else {
    # execute that part
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the fast response!!Sometimes the solution is simple!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if the vm file has all names on one line or each name on a line of its own.
For the former use -match, for the later replace -match with -contains.

```
$content = Get-Content vm.txt

get-vm | 
where-object { $_.Name -match $content } | 
foreach-object {  'execute this part'}
```